# git, как убрать из истории записи о merge

Tags: git, git-merge

Поиск не помог, так как не могу сформулировать правильный запрос.

В общем есть бранч, в котором пара коммитов. Но беда в том, работа над ним шла долго и периодически приходилось делать merge из мастера, чтобы потом не сойти с ума разбирая конфликты.

Теперь, при создании PR, история на гитхабе выглядит примерно так:

```
Merge pull request #1 from ...
Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/...
Optimizing checks.  …
Merge pull request #2 from ...
Merge remote-tracking branch 'remotes/upstream/master' ...
Merge branch 'master' into ...
Remove wrong replacement
```

Полезной инфы ровно две строки, а остальное, по сути, шум. Можно как-то оставить информацию только по коммитам?

Comment: Сделайте git rebase https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 0):

Выполнить интерактивный `rebase`. merge-коммиты или пропустить или `squash`ить